# How to make this work without random but in turn?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

[image: 1st part of the code]

[image: 2d part of the code]

[image: 3d part of the code]

[image: 4th part of the code]

[image: 5th part of the code]

[image: 6th part of the code]

[image: 7th part of the code]

Can anyone help?
The cards on the table are generated randomly, according to this code, there are 5 cards.
The question is how to make them not randomly generated, but in turn, one by one

Comment: What do you mean by "in turn"?

Comment: one by one, there are only five cards, I want them in order, one by one

Comment: Sounds like you just need a counter for "how many cards I've already loaded". Increment that counter each time `NewCard` is called...

Comment: [**Why should I not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 1):

Just as in real live:

- Initially compose and shuffle the deck **once**

  You could do this using [Linq `OrderBy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderby) and as sort factor use [`Random.value`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Random-value.html).

  *Or if it is actually not even desired to be shuffled then just ignore this step.*
- Then draw cards sequentially from the shuffled deck

  I would use a [`Queue`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.queue-1) which basically is the closest to a real live card deck: First-in first-out collection which allows to draw a card and at the same time remove it from the deck.

So something like e.g.

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

...

private Queue<Card> deck;

public void InitializeDeck()
{
    deck = new Queue<Card>(resourseManager.cards.OrderBy(c => Random.value));
    // or if you want to skip the randomization entirely simply skip the OrderBy part
    //deck = new Queue<Card>(resourseManager.cards);
}

public void NewCard()  
{
    if(deck == null)
    {
        Debug.LogError($"{nameof(deck)} is not initialized! You need to call {nameof(Initialize)} before you can call {nameof(NewCard)}!", this);
        return;
    }

    if(deck.Count == 0)
    {
        Debug.LogError($"No cards available, {nameof(deck)} is empty!", this);
        return;
    }  

    // returns the next card and removes it from the deck
    var card = deck.Dequeue();

    LoadCard(card);
}
```

Comment: thank you! I have added images of the code, may be now you can ask me more specifically;

Comment: Assets\Scripts\GameManager.cs(161,90): error CS0103: The name 'Initialize' does not exist in the current context